# Model 'feedback' is not associated to Model 'user' - Sequelize (Node JS)

Tags: sequelize.js

I am working on an application where I want to retrieve data from two tables.

`USERS` and `FEEDBACKS`

Every user has multiple feedbacks, hence 1 to many relations between `USERS` and `FEEDBACKS`. I am using Sequelize for modeling. I have created two Models, with the following format. The `ratedBy` in `FEEDBACKS` points to the `id` of `USERS`. I also created associations between the two tables.

```js
const { sequelize } = require('../db_connection')

const Model = Sequelize.Model;

//Creating User model
class User extends Model { }
User.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        defaultValue: "",
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    avatar: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'user' })


//Creating Feedback model
class Feedback extends Model { }
Feedback.init({
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    comment: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
    },
    rating: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    },
    ratedBy: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: User,
            key: 'id'
        }
    },
    createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
    updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE,
}, { sequelize, modelName: 'feedback' })

User.associate = () => {
    User.hasMany(Feedback, { as: 'ratedBy' })
}

Feedback.associate = () => {
    Feedback.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'ratedBy' });
}
```

The models can be migrated successfully. When I try to run the query to return all the feedbacks with and users from the respective tables, it simply throws an error says `Model 'feedback' is not associated with Model 'user'`.

I went through different StackOverflow answers and tried different answers but all in vain.

```js
const { User, Feedback } = require('./models')

//Migrate the User Model
User.sync({ alter: true })

//Migrate the Feedback Model
Feedback.sync({ alter: true })

const models = {
    User, Feedback
};

Object.keys(models).forEach(model => {
    console.log(models[model])
    if ('associate' in models[model]) {
        models[model].associate(models);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been trying for a while and found the solution. I just had to make little changes.

I changed the associations to this.

```js
User.hasMany(Feedback, { foreignKey: 'ratedBy' })
Feedback.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'ratedBy' });
```

Changed my query to this :

```js
Feedback.findAll({
        attributes: ['comment', 'rating', 'createdAt', 'ratedBy'],
        include: [{
            model: User,
            as: 'user',
            attributes: ['name', 'avatar'],
        }]
    })
        .then(feedbacks => res.send(feedbacks))
```

I also removed the manual associations for each model.

```js
const models = {
    User, Feedback
};

Object.keys(models).forEach(model => {
    console.log(models[model])
    if ('associate' in models[model]) {
        models[model].associate(models);
    }
})
```